# PostgreSQL - Use event trigger to validate a trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, ddl

Is it possible to use an EVENT TRIGGER to validate a TRIGGER definition?

What I want is to guarantee that the trigger is fired AFTER a STATEMENT, on INSERT or UPDATE but not on delete, like the follow example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON mytable
   FOR EACH STATEMENT
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE myprocedure();
```

I know I can check those parameters inside the trigger function with TG_OP, TG_WHEN and TG_LEVEL, but in this way, it only checks if the trigger is correct during an insertion, upload or deletion, and not right after the trigger definition.

Comment: No. However, a clever system is to name the trigger functions according to what they're expected to be used, e.g. `tf_mytable_after_iu()`.

Comment: Ziggy: Huh? Why can't you use an event trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that uses the [trigger__parse](https://github.com/decibel/cat_tools/blob/master/sql/cat_tools.sql#L339) function in [cat_tools](http://pgxn.org/dist/cat_tools/), which you can install with [pgxnclient](http://pgxnclient.projects.pgfoundry.org/).

First, some general setup:

```
CREATE EXTENSION cat_tools;
CREATE TABLE i(i int);
```

Create the actual event trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION no_before_triggers() RETURNS event_trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $body$
DECLARE
  r record;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
  LOOP
    IF (cat_tools.trigger__parse(r.objid)).timing = 'BEFORE' THEN
        RAISE 'before triggers not allowed';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END$body$;
```

Finally, try creating a BEFORE trigger and see that it fails:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dummy BEFORE INSERT ON i EXECUTE PROCEDURE tg_dummy();
ERROR:  before triggers not allowed
```